# Prolog Binary Numbers of length N

Tags: list, binary, prolog

How i could create a predicate in order to enlist all possible combinations of binary numbers of length N?

Example -> If length N = 3 then the output is

L = [0,0,0]

L = [0,0,1]

L = [0,1,0]

L = [0,1,1]

L = [1,0,0]

L = [1,0,1]

L = [1,1,0]

L = [1,1,1]

false

Comment: `length(L, N), L ins 0..1, labeling([],L)` using `library(clpz)` or `library(clpfd)`

Comment: what if i want to do it without any library, also nice name (hehe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
binary_list(0,[]).
binary_list(N,[X|Xs]) :-
    N > 0,
    member(X,[0,1]),
    N1 is N-1,
    binary_list(N1,Xs).
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly how this works?

Comment: the first binary_list just tells us that a list of length zero is empty

  the next binary_list says that  for  a list of length N
  it will be made of an X and an Xs.
  The X will be either a 0 or 1  # from the member
  and the Xs will be a binary_list of length N-1

  basically we will be recursively  creating lists by taking first a 0 then a 1 and putting 
  it in front of  all binary list combinations of that are shorter by 1.

  sometimes it helps to just look at the prolog code as a description of what is true 
  and just trust it to do the work within those constraints